# Resetting a ticker

Tags: multithreading, go, timer, ticker

Consider a server that is initialised with a timer/ticker resource that will fire every `t` (`t` is 20ms in my example) ticks. Every time the server listens to something on the network (like a periodic signal from peers), it has to reset the timer. On the other hand if the timer expires without a reset (for example, all of its peers are dead), it triggers some event (I'm just printing the time from start of program in my example).

I'm having trouble implementing this behaviour using `time.Ticker`. Resetting the timer seems to work (it does not fire for the first 50ms), but the ticker is not active (doesn't tick every 20ms) after that.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var wallclock time.Time

type server struct {
    timeout *time.Ticker
    stop    chan bool
}

func (srv *server) start() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-srv.timeout.C:
            {
                elapsed := time.Since(wallclock)
                fmt.Println("timed out after ", elapsed, " elapsed from start ")
            }
        case <-srv.stop:
            {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    wallclock = time.Now()
    //make the server with a timer that will fire every 20ms
    srv := server{
        timeout: time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond),
        //channel to indicate the server to stop listening
        stop:    make(chan bool),
    }
    //start listening on a different thread 
    go srv.start()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        //reset it every 10ms
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        srv.timeout.Stop()
        //as the reset frequency is higher, 
        //I'm not expecting this to fire within 
        //the first 50ms (5*10ms)
        srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    //sleep for 110ms
    //I'm expecting the timer to fire at least 5 times here
    time.Sleep(110 * time.Millisecond)
    //stop listening
    srv.stop <- true
    fmt.Println("Hi from tckr!")
}
```

I'm expecting to see something like

```
timed out after ~70ms elapsed from start
timed out after ~90ms elapsed from start
timed out after ~110ms elapsed from start
timed out after ~130ms elapsed from start
timed out after ~150ms elapsed from start
Hi from tckr!
```

Five times because I let the main thread sleep for 110ms and the 20ms timer could fire five times within this interval.

But I just see `Hi from tckr!`. Is `srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)` the proper way to reset `Ticker` ?

If I don't stop the ticker within the `for` loop (`srv.timeout.Stop()`), the ticker seems to keep ticking. Here's a sample output after commenting `srv.timeout.Stop()`.

```
timed out after  20.6872ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  41.4278ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  61.8747ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  72.7793ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  94.1448ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  112.5283ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  134.0131ms  elapsed from start
timed out after  152.5846ms  elapsed from start
Hi from tckr!
```

I don't want the ticker to fire within the first 50ms (i.e, I don't want to see the first two lines with 20.6872ms and 41.4278ms).

Comment: You're setting a ticker for 20ms, but stopping it after 10ms,  and doing this 5 times, so it never times out.

Comment: This sounds like a simple timeout mechanism, so you don't need a `Ticker` (which fires every `t`), you just need a `Timer` (which fires once, after `t`). In either case, to reset, just stop the existing ticker/timer and create a new one.

Comment: @Adrian I want the "fire every `t`" - periodic timeout behaviour. According to your comment, `Ticker` seems to be the right choice for this use case. The server needs to do this as long as it is up and running (until I stop it), not just once (hence the infinite `for`).

Comment: @bserdar If I don't `Stop()` it, it seems to keep ticking. Please see the additional output I've added.

Comment: @bserdar so you want it to time out repeatedly? Your description says "if the timer expires", but a ticker never expires, it ticks; it "it triggers some event" over and over again until you stop it. Also, in your `for...select` in `start()`, it will not notice when you replace the ticker. The `case`s are evaluated once when it enters the `select`, then it waits for a message on each channel; replacing the tickers out from under it will have no effect, it still waits on the old channel.

Comment: @Adrian you're right, I missed that

Comment: @Adrian Ah! Thanks for explaining. I thought that I was replacing the old channel and making the `start()` thread listen on the new `Ticker` channel I created. So is there a way I can do this from outside without having stop the `start()` goroutine/thread ?

Comment: `srv.timeout.Stop(); srv.stop <- false; srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond); go srv.start()` within the `for` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, [for `select` statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send.

That means that once `start` enters its `select` statement, it evaluates `srv.timeout.C` and holds onto the channel; any change to `srv.timeout` after it enters the `select` will have no impact on the `select`, it will still be waiting to receive from the channel it had before.

You could get around this by adding another channel (in the example here named `ping`) so that you can signal to `start` that the channel is changing (or possibly move the entire reset logic into `start`):

```
type server struct {
    timeout *time.Ticker
    stop    chan bool
    ping    chan struct{}
}

func (srv *server) start() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-srv.timeout.C:
            elapsed := time.Since(wallclock)
            fmt.Println("timed out after ", elapsed, " elapsed from start ")
        case <-srv.ping:
            // do nothing & let the loop iterate
            // OR
            srv.timeout.Stop()
            srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)
        case <-srv.stop:
            return
        }
    }
}

// in main()
go srv.start()
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    //reset it every 10ms
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    srv.ping <- struct{}{}

    // possibly shift the below logic to start()'s ping handler case
    srv.timeout.Stop()
    srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why doing `srv.timeout.Stop(); srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)` from within the main thread (as you've shown) works ? I appears that I'm doing the same thing: deliver a ping (for which the other thread does nothing and loops back over to wait on `select`), and then change the underlying channel to something else from outside the `select` statement. If "any change to `srv.timeout` after it enters the `select` will have no impact on the `select`", how does this work ?

Comment: Ah! that appears to be a race. Works mostly, but shows its teeth occasionally (just prints `Hi from tckr!`). I think, if the main thread manages to reset the timer before the other thread enters the `select` it works, but it fails if the other thread begins to wait on the `select` before `main` could reset the timer. If you agree, please remove that part from the answer. Anyway, thanks for the explanation. I shouldn't be doing two different things on the same channel.

Comment: Just to be clear: I claim `srv.timeout.Stop(); srv.timeout = time.NewTicker(20 * time.Millisecond)` has to be within the `ping` handler (within the `select` statement).

Comment: Yes, that's how it is in my example code. It's inside the ping handler case.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I agree. When you said `// possibly shift the below logic to start()'s ping handler case`  I just was trying both!